# How to create a login function without using spring security with grails 3 using interceptors

Tags: grails, grails3

System has two grails apps:

1. the private backoffice which uses springsecurity and an Operator domain object holding the operators username, password, number of failed logins etc.
2. the public web front end where users signup, login, and use the system.  The User domain object holds the users username, password etc.

Because we are using springsecuirty for the backoffice, I assume we cant use it again for the web (the config and db will conflict).  Also, the web just needs a very basic auth (all pages require a valid session except register and the login form itself).

Setting up the login form and the interceptor are easy.

The question is, what should the login form actually do in the controller?  I can check the username and password match whats in the DB, then I presumably need to create a session, with session timeouts etc. Where do I look for documentation on how to do this?  http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Servlet%20API/session.html Tells you how to logout, but not login. I presumably need to store sessions in the DB (so that the user can hit any server) etc.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at some of my old java code, I have got some of the way there.

The interceptor looks like this:

```
class AuthInterceptor {
    public AuthInterceptor() {
        // allow the login form and register form to work.
        matchAll().excludes(controller: 'auth')
    }
    boolean before() {
        if(session.getAttribute("user")== null ) {
            // jump to the login form if there is no user attribute.
            redirect controller: 'auth', action: 'login'
            return false
        }
        true
    }
    boolean after() { true }
    void afterView() {
        // no-op
    }
```

The controller looks like this:

```
class AuthController {
    def index() { }

    def login() {
        def email = params.email
        def password = params.password

        if (email != null) {
            // It would be better to invalidate the old session
            // but if we do, we cant get a new one...
            // session.invalidate()

            User user = User.findByEmail(email);
            if (user != null) {
                log.error("user.pass:" +  user.password +  " pass:" + password)
                // @TODO handle password encryption
                if (user.password == password) {
                    session.setAttribute("user", user)
                    redirect(controller:"dashboard")
                }
            }
            flash.message = "email or password incorrect"
        }
        render (view:"login")
    } // login()
```

However, I have not found where we can set the session timeout yet.

Comment: I don't think this is going to be a good idea, the todo handle encryption might be difficult if you are going to try decrypt their pass from spring security encrypted password or to match it somehow - your best bet is to run backend with springsecurity and springsecurity-rest  - you can use https://github.com/grails-samples/grails-spring-security-rest-java-client there  is groovy version of this as well in your front end application then using the username / pass send to rest backend get jwt token - this properly logs in a user to backend and lets spring security handle password verification

Comment: alternatively if you wrote your frontend app in some reactive front end such as react/vuejs/angular you would find it auto fits into your rest backend without the jwt token app I suggested - would mean interacting in rest and sending token on each request to backend - although its hard to make out if beyond auth you need the other app for much else